# Calculate the normal and geodesic curvature of this curves on a cylinder.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am having a lot of trouble reading some questions for Differential geometry.

The question states.

Compute the normal and geodesic curvature of these curves on the cylinder C.

$C= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb {R^{3}} : x^2 + y^2 =1 \} $

$ \alpha_{1} (t)= (cos (t), sin (t),0) $

The thing thats confusing me is i have that $K_n = <\alpha^{''} (t),\dot n > $ (the normal curvature is the second derivative of alpha dot product the normal vector)
But for some reason in my notes all the examples $ \dot n = \alpha (t) $

i.e

$K_n = <\alpha^{''} (t),\alpha (t) > $

$K_g = \alpha^{''} - \alpha (t) (<\alpha^{''} (t),\alpha (t) >) $

Why is the normal vector always just $\alpha (t) $ and why bother even writing $ \dot n $ if that's always the case?
Also why define the surface that the curve is on if it has nothing to do with the calculations?

Anyway im misunderstanding something any help much appreciated.

Comment: You want to see how much of the "curvature vector" $\kappa N$ of the curve is *normal* to the surface (that will tell you normal curvature, up to sign) and how much of it is *tangent* to the surface (that's the geodesic curvature). Geodesics on the surface are characterized by geodesic curvature = 0.

Comment: i Actually understand the words in what your saying... but it doesn't answer my question or if it does i don't know why.  Why is the normal vector to the curve on the surface just $ \alpha_1 (t) $ ?

Comment: The unit normal to the cylinder (pointing outward) is the position vector of that circle, yes. Either draw the picture or just do the calculation with a parametrization of the cylinder. And the principal normal of the circle is the negative of that.